# Subclass WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with @EnableWebSecurity, getting java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity` to handle basic spring web security:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

When I extend this class, the subclass does not get loaded by Spring, nor are its methods invoked, i.e.:

```
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends SecurityConfig {
...
}
```

When I add `@Primary` and `@EnableWebSecurity` to my subclass, I get this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used on...`

How do I tell Spring to use my subclass in lieu of its parent when creating the security object?

Comment: You can avoid extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter at all, see https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 0):

You will get this exception if there are two or more classes that implement `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation and they have same priority.

`@Order` is used to specify priority in which the beans will be loaded or prioritized by Spring. Lower numbers indicate a higher priority.

So you can do something like this:

```
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

and for a subclass :

```
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends SecurityConfig{
}
```

In this way, Spring will give priority to the child class when creating a security object since it has higher priority

Comment: This half works - My custom class is loaded by Spring, but a Component of the subclass is also loaded.  I want my custom class _instead_ of the base class.